# How can I give each <li> its own bullet image?

Tags: css, styling

I have tried

```
<ul id="contact_list">
    <li id="phone">Local 604-555-5555</li>
    <li id="i18l_phone">Toll-Free 1-800-555-5555</li>
</ul>
```

with

```
#contact_list
{
    list-style: disc none inside;
}

#contact_list #phone
{
    list-style-image: url(images/small_wood_phone.png);
}

#contact_list #i18l_phone
{
    list-style-image: url(images/i18l_wood_phone.png);
}
```

to no avail. Only a disc appears. If I want each individual list item to have it's own bullet, how can I accomplish this with css, ***without using background images***.

Edit : I have discovered that, despite what firebug tells me, the list-style-image rule is being overridden somehow. If I inline the rule, like so:

```
    <li id="phone" style="list-style-image: url(images/small_wood_phone.png);">Local 604-555-5555</li>
```

then all is well. Since I have no other rules in the test case I'm running that contains ul or li in the selector, I'm not sure why inlining gives a different result.

Comment: Yes I know where the images are, and confirmed that they work in other contexts. And I thought I was fairly specific in saying that what I needed was the li's bullets to work, and not put them into a background image. Perhaps I wasn't.

Comment: are you including your CSS file from a different directory than your html/php/whatever? If so, you might just double check that because if the CSS is included it still goes finds images relative to the CSS file...

Just a sanity test.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it works for that. I can change the disc, or inside/outside, at that shows up. just not the image, unless i inline it. I'm working on increasing the specificity to see if I can out-specify whatever it is without inlining the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine whether you are in "quirks" mode or not, because for many CSS properties it makes a difference.

Secondly, the W3c [specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image) that the URL should be in double quotes (although I don't use the quotes, either). Go with the spec to save yourself trouble down the line.

If you are specifying "strict" in your DOCTYPE, then the browser may require the double quotes, per the standard.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
#contact_list li
{
    list-style: none;
}

#contact_list li#phone
{
    list-style-image: url('images/small_wood_phone.png');
}

#contact_list li#i18l_phone
{
    list-style-image: url('images/i18l_wood_phone.png');
}
```

Comment: The only other thing I can think might be an issue is if your styles are in a styles folder on the root and your images are in another folder.  In which case you need to set your image paths to /images/small_wood_phone.png, for example.

Comment: How many list items have the id="phone" and id="i18l_phone"?  If there's more than one of each I would highly recommend using classes instead.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but you're using relative links to your images. When you use relative links in css, it is relative to the css file, but if it is inlined, it will be relative to the html page.

Comment: This is the almost certainly the actual answer, especially given Dustman's answer-response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209980/how-can-i-give-each-li-its-own-bullet-image/210232#210232

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, I tried your code it it works. The only time it doesn't is if the images are not present. Maybe you need to check to see that the images you specify in the CSS are actually in the folder images or not misspelled.

NOTE: IN both firefox and ie.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing it slightly differently, in the CSS - i.e.:

```
#contact_list
{
  list-style: none;
}

#contact_list li {
  padding-left: 20px; /* assumes the icons are 16px */
}

#contact_list #phone
{
  background: url(images/small_wood_phone.png) no-repeat top left;
}

#contact_list #i18l_phone
{
  background: url(images/i18l_wood_phone.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might double check that those images are where you think they are. This example works fine unless the images are missing.

Answer (score 2):

I never would have thought. If I quote the url, like so:

```
#contact_list #phone
{
    list-style-image: url("/images/small_wood_phone.png");
}
```

it starts working. I unquote it, and it stops. I thought that's not supposed to make a difference.

Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: it wasn't the quotes, its the fact that you started it with "/images" instead of just "images"

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding list-style-type: none; to #contact-list? Perhaps even instead of your list-style: declaration.

Comment: No dice there. I tried removing that declaration too, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It pains me to suggest it, but have you tried the !important flag? Also, does it behave the same in other browsers? What if this is something you have in your Firefox userChrome.css file?

Comment: Good thought, but, no Safari/Opera/IE do the same thing. Well, IE doesn't, it thoroughly borks the padding and margins, but that is a whole different story...

Comment: Man that's really odd that !important wouldn't fix your style overridden problem. Thinking...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding !important after the list-style-image property, which would prevent it from being overridden.

Answer (score -1):

```
#contact_list
{
    list-style: disc none inside;
}

#contact_list #phone
{
    background-image: url(images/small_wood_phone.png) no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: <image width>px;
}

#contact_list #i18l_phone
{
    background-image: url(images/i18l_wood_phone.png) no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: <image width>px;
}
```